# How do I install Python packages/ wxPython on Mac OSX?

Tags: python, module, wxpython

I'm very new to python and any non-basic computer functions in general, but I'm having a very basic problem and I can't figure out how to fix it. Any time I download a module from the internet and try to import it in python, I get an error message. For example, I just downloaded wxPython after being instructed to do so on a tutorial program for Python I've been  using, and after entering "import wx" I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    import wx
ImportError: No module named wx
```

How do I fix this so that python can find modules I download? 
Thanks!!

Python version 2.7.3, and I downloaded wxPython from the download link on the website. Another thing I noticed: whenever I type in python setup.py install in the Terminal, I get:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Which seems to be another huge problem?

Comment: We'd need a lot more information: Operating system, python version, and how you download and install the modules.

Comment: when you are looking for solutions on how to fix this, make sure you look *specifically* for Mac OSX answers, because the answer is different for OS X vs. other systems.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you need to do to actually debug this:

1. Run python and check what version you are running.
2. type `where python` and figure out if you have multiple versions of python running at once.
3. With `pip` or `easy_install`, read the output to check where they are installing packages. It's somewhat likely that they are installing to the system-wide Python 2.6, as opposed to the version that you want it to be installed to (Python 2.7).
4. If you find any packages installed in the wrong place with 3, uninstall them with `pip uninstall <packagename>` and then specifically reinstall them to 2.7 with `easy_install-2.7` or `pip-2.7` install. If you don't see the option for `easy_install-2.7` or `pip-2.7`, you need to install [distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute) and run its `setup.py` file with the specific version of Python you are using.
5. Make sure you are actually in the directory when running `setup.py`. For example, to install distribute, you need to `cd` into the appropriate directory to install.

Finally, a separate note: it's *far* easier to install packages with `easy_install` or `pip`, as opposed to downloading them separately. You should try doing that first.  Again, [distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute) has more info.

Comment: I'm sorry what do I type "where python" into?

Comment: on to the command line.  you might be better off going over to http://superuser.com instead (another stack exchange site) -- they probably will be able to help you better with setting up python.